# Error: The provided credentials do not have permission to create the service-linked role for EC2 Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I'm running into an error when creating a spot fleet request through cloudformation. The request is created but I'm getting the error mentioned in the title when the fleet attempts to request an instance.

The permissions needed are described in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#spot-fleet-prerequisites), however when I try to follow the steps to create the `AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet` role I don't have the option to choose "EC2 - Spot Fleet", only EC2 FLeet. What's odd is that when I create the CF stack it actually does create that service linked role for me.

My user has admin credentials and I'm using the "aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role" as the fleet role.

As I understand it the service linked role just needs to exist in order for this to work, but I'm unable to create it manually.
I am able to successfully create the fleet via the console, using the exact same values as what I'm using in the template and I choose the same "aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role" there as well.

I also gave my user the IAM credentials mentioned in that document, even though it's admin, just to see if I needed the pass through permission, but as I understand I only really need that if I'm supplying an instance profile in the launch specification, which I'm not. This is my resource definition in the template:

````yaml
     SpotFleetRequestConfigData: 
        TargetCapacity: 1
        IamFleetRole:  arn:aws:iam::73682036499:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role
        LaunchSpecifications: 
          - ImageId: '{{resolve:ssm:TestImage:4}}' #param stored reference to AMI
            InstanceType: t2.small
            NetworkInterfaces:
              - SubnetId: !ImportValue CustomVPCStack-dmz-subnet-1
                DeviceIndex: 0
                Groups:
                  - !Ref EC2MCServerSecurityGroup
            TagSpecifications:
              - 
                ResourceType: instance
                Tags: 
                  - 
                    Key: Name
                    Value: spotfleetserver
        ReplaceUnhealthyInstances: true
        Type: maintain #default```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works through the console is because it attaches the correct IAM instance profile. That's missing from your `SpotFleetRequestConfigData`.

I was trying to create a spot fleet request as well but using Terraform and I got the same error. Based on the code snippet in the question, I believe the correct syntax is:

```
SpotFleetRequestConfigData:
  LaunchSpecifications:
    iamInstanceProfile:
      arn: arn:aws:iam:::instance-profile/instance-compute-full-access
```

Note: you probably have to add your account ID to the ARN and a role with lesser permission than full compute access may also work.

Answer (score 11):

It's likely your AWS account is old enough that it didn't have the service-linked role created. Issue the following command with Admin permissions to create the role with the proper trust:

```
aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name spot.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: I did try that yeah, my user has Admin permissions, but I also just tried it with the root user and I still get the same error. When I create the stack I can see that my spot fleet is creating the "AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet" role when it makes the request for an instance. So it obviously has the permission to create roles, but not the spot service-linked role. When I look in the Create Role section under the Choose a use case I don't see the option to choose EC2 - Spot or Spot Fleet service, is that expected?

Comment: I tried to run a load test with RedLine13 (that helps create spot instances on AWS) and encountered the issue. Your cli command helps!

Comment: Note: As also stated by the author of the original answer, in new accounts you don't need to create it manually (see [docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html#:~:text=You%20don%27t%20need%20to%20manually%20create%20a%20service%2Dlinked%20role))

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work, though I'm still not entirely clear why. When I create a Spot Fleet through the console, the default role selected is the "aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role". This is the role I was using for the fleet resource definition in my cloudformation template, but it would result in the IAM error I mentioned. I first tried making sure the service linked roles I needed were created, described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/spot_fleet_IAM_role.html. But I was still getting the error while using the spot fleet tagging role. I could only get it to complete an instance request successfully after creating a new policy with the following permissions:

```
"ec2:DescribeImages",
"ec2:TerminateInstances",
"ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
"ec2:CreateTags",
"ec2:RunInstances",
"ec2:DescribeSubnets",
"ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus"
```

and

```
"iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
"iam:ListRoles",
"iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
```

The tagging role I was using previously only had the first set of permissions for ec2, not the IAM permissions. If anyone has a better answer I'll take it, because as I said it's still not clear why when I use the tagging role in the console it works, but through cloudformation it results in the IAM error. When I create the stack I'm not specifying any IAM permissions, so it should be using the same permissions as my user, which is an admin user.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create that role as it is service linked role. Use the below command to create this role and you are done.

```
aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name spot.amazonaws.com
```